# Firewall not turning on after executing the program

Tags: vbscript

```
Dim command
Dim status

command = "psexec \\ 172.16.11.63 netsh advfirewall firewall set opmode "
status = "enable"

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")

oShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\PSexec\"
oShell.Run "command.com /k " & command & status

Set oShell = Nothing
```

Hi, I have a sample script here that suppose to enable my firewall if it is disabled, but it doesn't work, however if I change my `status` to `disable` and my firewall was turned on, after executing the program, the enabled firewall will be disabled. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing commands for different versions of Windows. According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709) article you should use

```
netsh firewall set opmode ENABLE
```

in older versions, but in 2008 and Vista (and I assume Win7 too) you should be using

```
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile state on
```

So either remove the `advfirewall` from your command if it's XP or 2003, or change it completely to the new command if it's a newer Windows version.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, I have another question, I am currently using Windows XP and if I run the 'enable' script, the error shows: 'The following command not found: advfirewall firewall set opmode enable' but the said command exists in my script. Any ideas on why this error keep on showing this?

Comment: The message means that `netsh` can't find any reference of the command within itself, since it's incorrect. If you remove the `advfirewall` bit from your script I think it should work.

Comment: @theglove - forgot to add the @ bit to my previous comment so you might not have been notified of it.